# A small technical explanation of nuclear energy

Tags: nuclear-physics

I don't know if this is the place to ask this kind of questions but I'm sure you guys can help me. I'm looking for a small (4 pages max.) technical explanation of nuclear energy, preferably of an academic source. It would be best if the physics and mathematics involved is understandable by last-year high school students. Can anybody help me out?

Thanks,

Arnoud

Comment: Wikipedia would probably give you exactly that

Comment: Did you try school books?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_power

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the academic source - someone directly involved with physics would just not be interested in this kind of text.
But look for introductions for academic fields that are only remotely/lightly involved with nuclear physics, maybe medicine or biology.

And: Not the right place for this I think.